# Fieldset loses styling in print view

Tags: html, css, printing, preview, fieldset

There is information displayed in a fieldset that is taken from a database in a content management system.

The information is styled correctly when viewed as a normal page, however when the page is viewed in print preview, the information in the fieldset is aligned to the left of the page and the styling is lost!

I have looked everywhere for a solution, people have mentioned removing the floats etc, however I can't seem to solve this problem!

The problem seems to occur in all browsers I have tried (Safari, Chrome and Firefox).

There is a small amount of data presented in a table, which is formatted correctly :/

**View from page:**
[page view](http://d.pr/i/EdCN)

**View from print preview:**
[print view](http://d.pr/i/DcBN)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*EDIT: These are small snippets of code as requested - there is a lot there!*

**HTML**

```
<div class="divClass" id="Person_title_div" >
    <label class="divLabel"  for='Person_title' id="Person_title.label"
            >Title </label>
    <div class="divValue">
    <input type="hidden" name="Person.title" value="-5509180968589174739" />
    <a href="../Title/view.jsp?id=-5509180968589174739&myCode=A1925C9679A8851CCA17D1269771AD4F"><span  >Dr</span></a>
</div>

</div>           

<div class="divClass" id="Person_knownAs_div" >
    <label class="divLabel"  for='Person_knownAs' id="Person_knownAs.label"
            >Name </label>
    <div class="divValue">

    <span  >qwe qwe</span>
</div>

</div>          

<div class="divClass" id="Person_email_div" >
    <label class="divLabel"  for='Person_email' id="Person_email.label"
            >Email </label>
    <div class="divValue">

    <span  >qwe@qew</span>
</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.divClass,
div.formWidget,
div.multiList {
  float: left;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 5px 5px 0;
  min-height:30px;
  width:310px;
}

fieldset {
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
```

**print.css**

```
/* print styles */

body {  background: white;  font-size: 8pt;     font-family: Verdana, Arial; }

#firstMenu,

#secondMenu,

#additionalMenu,

#footernav,

#selectheader ul,

input,

a img#logo {    width: 58px;    height: 70px; }

a:link, a:visited {     color: #520;    background: transparent;    font-weight: normal;    text-decoration: none; }

header {    height: 105px;  background: url(images/header.gif) no-repeat; }

div#mainData td, div#mainData th {      float: none !important;     display: inline !important;     padding-left: 1em;      padding-right: 1em;  }

table.datatable th, table.datatable td {

    vertical-align: top;

    /*For some reason table text is coming out inconsistent.  Must be being inherited somewhere, 

    but difficult to pin down.  Therefore force to specific pixel value as a work around */

    font-size: 9px;

}/* CSS Document */

.menu {
    display: none; }

.session {
    display: none; }
```

Comment: we need your code to help you

Comment: Hi david, I've added some code as requested.